# OpenLayers 3 with Feature Grid

Tags: openlayers, geoext, geoext-2

I cannot find examples of OL3 integration with EXT, such as done with GeoExt.  It looks like GeoExt is waiting for funding to do this. What I want is a feature grid with vector data displayed in a table/grid and two-way interaction between selected features in the map and the grid. This is done in may OL 2 and GeoExt examples, but I haven't seen anything like this with OpenLayers 3.

Can anyone point me to such examples/documentation?

Comment: It's still WIP. Stay tuned with the GeoEXT project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

There are not public examples because it's not currently done in GeoExt (maybe too early).

If you need this function, you will have to manage it on your own, at application level. The "two way data bindings" can be done using for example something like http://extjs.eu/example-complex-data-binding-5/

Search "two way binding extjs" in any search engine for more.